# Camel with servlet not starting in quarkus

Tags: java, apache-camel, quarkus

I am trying to start my application with Apache camel and Quarkus but it giving me below error:

> At least one bean matched the required type and qualifiers but was marked as unused and removed during build
> Removed beans:
> - CLASS bean org.apache.camel.component.servlet.CamelHttpTransportServlet [types=[class javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet, interface java.io.Serializable, class org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet, interface javax.servlet.ServletConfig, interface org.apache.camel.http.common.HttpRegistryProvider, class org.apache.camel.component.servlet.CamelHttpTransportServlet, class javax.servlet.GenericServlet, interface javax.servlet.Servlet], qualifiers=[@javax.enterprise.inject.Default(),
> @javax.enterprise.inject.Any()]]
> Required type: class org.apache.camel.component.servlet.CamelHttpTransportServlet
> Required qualifiers: [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default()]
> Solutions:
> - Application developers can eliminate false positives via the @Unremovable annotation
> - Extensions can eliminate false positives via build items, e.g. using the UnremovableBeanBuildItem

I am not sure what am I missing:

```
application.properties
camel.context.name=aiv
quarkus.camel.servlet.url-patterns = /rest/*

pom.xml
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-quarkus-main</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-quarkus-platform-http</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-quarkus-log</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-quarkus-timer</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-quarkus-servlet</artifactId>
</dependency>


public class CamelRoute extends RouteBuilder {

  @Override
  public void configure() {
     restConfiguration()
            .component("servlet");
    ...
  }
}
```

Please let me know what wrong am I doing?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you genuinely need Servlet support for some reason, then you can rely on `camel-quarkus-platform-http` to handle the HTTP transport for the Camel REST DSL.

You're dependencies can be simplified to:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-quarkus-main</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-quarkus-log</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-quarkus-timer</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-quarkus-rest</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

There's more information in the Camel Quarkus documentation:

https://camel.apache.org/camel-quarkus/latest/reference/extensions/platform-http.html

Comment: If remove that I am getting this error:                              ERROR [org.apa.cam.qua.mai.CamelMainRuntime] (Quarkus Main Thread) Failed to start application: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1 at: >>> onCompletion[[SetHeader[notificationCount, bean[ref:n method:getNotificationAllCount(${header.owner},${header.roles})]]]] <<< in route: Route(route1)[From[rest://post:xxxxxx@0x354c2b85]]], onCompl... because of No language could be found for: bean

Comment: If you're using the bean language then you need to add a dependency on `camel-quarkus-bean`. https://camel.apache.org/camel-quarkus/latest/reference/extensions/bean.html

Comment: Hey nice, that worked, I thought as Quarkus creating bean this will not be required.